# Remove multi object from arraylist JAVA

Tags: java

```
  ArrayList<String> TestList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    indexList.add(1);
    indexList.add(3);
    indexList.add(4);
    TestList .add("String1");
    TestList .add("String2");
    TestList .add("String3");
    TestList .add("String4");
    TestList .add("String5");
    TestList .add("String6");
    for (Integer x : indexList) {
        TestList.remove(x);
    }
    for (String x : TestList ) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

I want to remove objects at 1,3,4 (in TestList), but result: [image]

Comment: Um...you removed the contents of `ListTest`, not `TestList`, what did you expect?

Comment: `ListTest` is not defined

Comment: Please read about java naming conventions. Variable names go **camelCase**.

Comment: Beyond that: you are calling `remove(Integer)` which tries to delete objects that are equal to the parameter. Try x.intValue() instead ;-)

Comment: First problem: you are calling `remove(Object)` (which is by removing equals values) instead of `remove(int)` (which is by index).  Fix by `list.remove((int) x);`  Second problem: once you removed an element, index of subsequent elements will be shifted down by 1.  You need to find a way to tackle it